# Understanding the Gradle "task" syntax

Tags: angular, gradle, npm

I am struggling to understand the Gradle "task" syntax.

I followed a howto and defined a `build.gradle`, to build an Angular4/SpringBoots projects with gradle.

The `build.gradle` contains several `task` blocks:

```
// add our development build NpmTask named buildClientDev
task buildClientDev(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    group = 'build'
    description = 'Compile client side folder for development'
    args = ['run', 'buildDev']
}


task buildClient(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    group = 'build'
    description = "Compile client side folder for production"
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

// setup watcher on this ng build to link to our overall java development build.
task buildClientWatch(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    group = 'application'
    description = "Build and watches the client side assets for rebuilding"
    args = ['run', 'buildWatch']
}
```

The application is started via gradle, by executing the Gradle command `./gradlew bootRun`

**Questions:**

- Who defines the syntax for those task-blocks? One of the plugins I applied?
- Are `buildDev, build, buildWatch` NPM or Gradle commands?
- If those are NPM commands - where is the connection to the Gradle's `gradlew bootrun` command? How does Gradle know, that they should be executed after  `gradlew bootrun` ?

---

**Full build.gradle:**

```
buildscript {
    ext {
        springBootVersion = '2.0.0.RELEASE'
    }
    repositories {
        jcenter()
        mavenCentral()
        maven {
            url "https://plugins.gradle.org/m2/"
        }
    }
    dependencies {
        classpath("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-gradle-plugin:${springBootVersion}")
        classpath "com.moowork.gradle:gradle-node-plugin:1.1.1"
    }
}


apply plugin: 'idea'
apply plugin: 'eclipse'
apply plugin: 'org.springframework.boot'
apply plugin: 'io.spring.dependency-management'
apply plugin: 'java'
// enable building wars: gradlew BootWar
apply plugin: 'war'

// fuilding frontend with npm
apply plugin: "com.moowork.node"

// add our development build NpmTask named buildClientDev
task buildClientDev(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    group = 'build'
    description = 'Compile client side folder for development'
    args = ['run', 'buildDev']
}


task buildClient(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    group = 'build'
    description = "Compile client side folder for production"
    args = ['run', 'build']
}

// setup watcher on this ng build to link to our overall java development build.
task buildClientWatch(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall') {
    group = 'application'
    description = "Build and watches the client side assets for rebuilding"
    args = ['run', 'buildWatch']
}

bootRun.dependsOn(buildClientDev)
jar.dependsOn(buildClient)

npm_run_build.inputs.dir new File(projectDir, "frontend")
npm_run_build.outputs.dir new File(projectDir, "build/dist")

group = 'de.webapp.spring'
version = '0.0.1-SNAPSHOT'
sourceCompatibility = 1.8
targetCompatibility = 1.8

repositories {
    mavenCentral()
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/snapshot" }
    maven { url "http://repo.spring.io/milestone" }
    maven { url 'https://repo.spring.io/libs-snapshot' }
}


dependencies {
    // makes the web application startable
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-web")
    testCompile('org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-test')

    //data
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-jpa")
    compile("org.springframework.boot:spring-boot-starter-data-rest")

    // RepositoryRestConfigurerAdapter
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-core"
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-webmvc"
    compile "org.springframework:spring-context"

    // enables HAL browser
    compile "org.springframework.data:spring-data-rest-hal-browser"

    // entity requirements
    compile "com.h2database:h2"
    compile "javax.xml.bind:jaxb-api"
}
```

**Update**:

The execution chain is the following, when doing `gradlew bootRun`

- Gradle. `gradlew bootRun` command >
- Gradle "moowork" plugin. buildClientDev task. Because of `bootRun.dependsOn(buildClientDev)`. >
- NPM. "buildDev" task. Because of `args = ['run', 'buildDev']` >
- Angular CLI. ng build. Because in package.json:  `buildDev": "ng
  build"`

The directed dependency graph of gradlew bootRun looks like this:

```
gradlew tasktree bootRun

> Task :taskTree

------------------------------------------------------------
Root project
------------------------------------------------------------

:bootRun
+--- :buildClientDev
|    +--- :npmInstall
|    |    \--- :npmSetup
|    |         \--- :nodeSetup
|    \--- :npmSetup
|         \--- :nodeSetup
\--- :classes
     +--- :compileJava
     \--- :processResources
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Who defines the syntax for those task-blocks? One of the plugins I applied?

The properties and methods available in the task block are defined by the "type" of the task. In this case it's `NpmTask` which comes from the `com.moowork.node` plugin

> Are buildDev, build, buildWatch NPM or Gradle commands?

They are tasks in the gradle model, of type `NpmTask` (which comes from the `com.moowork.node` plugin)

> If those are NPM commands - where is the connection to the Gradle's gradlew bootrun command? How does Gradle know, that they should be executed after  gradlew bootrun?

Again, `bootRun` is not a core Gradle task, It's added by the `org.springframework.boot` plugin. They are wired together in Gradle's [DAG](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Directed_acyclic_graph). I can see two  `dependsOn` declarations in your `build.gradle` which wire them together

- `bootRun.dependsOn(buildClientDev)`
- `task buildClientDev(type: NpmTask, dependsOn: 'npmInstall')`

If you want to visualise the DAG I suggest you add the [task-tree](https://github.com/dorongold/gradle-task-tree) plugin

```
plugins {
    id "com.dorongold.task-tree" version "1.3"
}
```

You could then run

```
./gradlew taskTree bootRun
```

And you'd get a task tree similar to the following (Note: this example for a totally different task tree)

```
:build
+---- :assemble
|    \--- :jar
|         \--- :classes
|              +--- :compileJava
|              \--- :processResources
\--- :check
     \--- :test
          +--- :classes
          |    +--- :compileJava
          |    \--- :processResources
          \--- :testClasses
               +--- :compileTestJava
               |    \--- :classes
               |         +--- :compileJava
               |         \--- :processResources
               \--- :processTestResources
```

Comment: Thanks lance. Now I understood the chain. And the plugin treeView is really a nice tipp.
`Gradle. "gradlew bootRun" command > 
Gradle "moowork" plugin. buildClientDev task. Because of bootRun.dependsOn(buildClientDev). >
NPM. "buildDev" task. Because of args = ['run', 'buildDev']. >
Angular CLI. ng build. Because in package.json:    "buildDev": "ng build",`

Comment: Not sure I fully grok your comment but glad to hear my answer has helped your understanding

Comment: I added an update to the question, where structured layout is allowed.